# How do I track where facebook likes are coming from?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, user-tracking

So, let's say I want to use a QR Code to ask someone to like my Facebook page.  I want to put this code in different media/ads, but want to add a variable to the like URL so I can track which media is working best.  Is there a way to do this?

I would like to track who "likes" through whichever code (or link, for that matter) so I can run different contests in different publications....each user that "likes" my business page is entered, but I need to know who goes with which contest.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `ref` parameter of [Like Button social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> `ref` - a label for tracking referrals; must be less than 50 characters and can contain alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (currently +/=-.:_). The ref attribute causes two parameters to be added to the referrer URL when a user clicks a link from a stream story about a Like action:
>
> - `fb_ref` - the ref parameter
> - `fb_source` - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'ticker', 'tickerdialog' or 'other') in which the click occurred and the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an underscore.